# Inputting double digit numbers from keyboard on Tkinter, Python

Tags: python, events, tkinter

So I'm using the following to enable single digit numbers to move the numbered tiles on my game board. However, I can't use the same method to input double digit numbers. Do you have any idea, how I could make Tkinter wait for me to input several digits as one number?

```
def key(event):
    if event.char.isdigit():
        for j, row in enumerate(board):
            for i, char in enumerate(row):
                if char.get() == event.char:
                play(i,j)
                return

root.bind('<Key>', key)
```

Comment: http://pastebin.com/WHQKcJkW

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I mention in previous question - you can put keys on list, wait a moment and check if there are two or more chars.

```
import tkinter as tk

''' catch two (or more) keys pressed in short time and tread it as one text '''
''' http://pastebin.com/WHQKcJkW '''

# --- functions ---

# keys buffer
keybuf = []


def test_after():

    # check if buffer is not empty
    if keybuf:

        # get all keys in buffer as one text
        text = ''.join(keybuf)

        # clear buffer
        keybuf.clear()

        # run some function here
        print('after:', text)    


def get_key(event):

    # save key in buffer    
    keybuf.append(event.char)

    # check buffer after 500ms (0.5s)
    root.after(500, test_after)

# --- main ---

root = tk.Tk()

root.bind('<Key>', get_key)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for me. keybuf.clear() is not working in Python as keybuf is a list. Any alternatives? Could you explain what this after loop does? It calls test_after? Because then, what captures the 2nd digit? Or does it call get_key again, append the new digit to the keybuf list and joins it in test_after?

Comment: `list.clear()` is available in Python 3. In Python2 you can use `keybuf = []` and you have to add `global keybuf` in `test_after`

Comment: I did do both of what you said, and it's messy still. Plus root.after(..) will keep looping through if nothing prompts it to stop,right?!

Comment: `after()` is not loop. It calls function only once. In example `after()` runs `test_after` 500ms after key was pressed.

Comment: but where does test_after capture the next inputted number?

Comment: everytime you press any key `get_key()` adds it to buffer. `get_key()` puts to buffer first digit and second digit (and third digit, and etc).

Comment: 500ms after first key `test_after` gets all keys from buffer. If you press two two buttons in less then 500ms then `test_after` get two chars.

Comment: I'm getting that now, but something is still not ok in test_after, as it prints the list of integers instead of the text string

Comment: strange, it should print text because there is `join` which connnect all digits in one string.

Comment: Ahh I got that within the test_after function now. How is this returned into get_key() when I actually would need that updated text string as my event.char?

Comment: `after()` puts function name and time on special list and `mainloop()` checks this time and runs this function - `test_after()` returns to `mainloop()`, not to `get_key()`. I think you don't need to return to `get_key()`. `get_key()` should have only two lines and nothings more. `test_after()` should call your function.